# How to resize, center align and make responsive a SVG file inside its parent div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to center an svg file into its parent div without success.

I have created this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/wfukyd4q/

where you can see I did the following:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 text-center">
    <div style="background-color:#489734;height:500px">
         <img src="https://42f2671d685f51e10fc6-b9fcecea3e50b3b59bdc28dead054ebc.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/illustrations/compose_music_ovo2.svg">
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to make the svg let's say 50% and put it in the centre, but to be responsive for mobile devices too.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried to set `width: 50%;` for your `img`?

Comment: @IrinaPotapova I did, but it makes sense only in the desktop. If you try it on mobile it looks tiny

Comment: it looks tiny because 50% of a mobilescreen is tiny. You can use a media query to adjust that

Comment: Hi its not technically an svg when you put it in an img tag. Just to let you know, if you wanted to adjust it like you would an svg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an image center (vertically & horizontally) inside a bigger div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388180/how-to-make-an-image-center-vertically-horizontally-inside-a-bigger-div)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical center svg in div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420338/vertical-center-svg-in-div-container)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your image has class `svg-image`:

```
<img class="svg-image" src="https://42f2671d685f51e10fc6-b9fcecea3e50b3b59bdc28dead054ebc.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/illustrations/compose_music_ovo2.svg">
```

Please add css similar to this:

```
.svg-image {
    width: 50%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    width: 90%;
}
```

You can specify several `@media` queries for different screen sizes and apply desired width of the image.

**EDIT:**

To center your image vertically and horizontally you can add styles to your div (which wraps your image):

```
.class-of-your-div {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how i keep it centered?

Comment: @EnexoOnoma, are asking about horizonal centering?

Comment: Vertically and horizontally

Comment: @EnexoOnoma, flexbox should work https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. Just need to add prefixes like here http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox. I've edited answer

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `background-*` properties will do what you want.

```css
div.text-center div {
  background-color: #489734;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("https://42f2671d685f51e10fc6-b9fcecea3e50b3b59bdc28dead054ebc.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/illustrations/compose_music_ovo2.svg");
  background-size: auto 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 text-center">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wfukyd4q/7/

If this doesn't exactly behave how you want on mobile devices, then you can use media queries to tweak the CSS as needed for certain screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the image element an Id then referencing that element inside of your CSS like so:

```
div#foo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

where your img tag has an example id of 'foo'

Update:

You might need to change the position of your parent like so:

```
  #parent {
    position: absolute

   }

div#foo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It does not center the image inside the div

Answer (score 0):

Yet an other way of doing it:

```css
.col-md-10{position:relative;}
.col-md-10 img{
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <div style="background-color:#489734;height:500px">
                    <img src="https://42f2671d685f51e10fc6-b9fcecea3e50b3b59bdc28dead054ebc.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/illustrations/compose_music_ovo2.svg">
                </div>

</div>
```